# How to post json document into bucket using N1QL REST API in Couchbase

Tags: rest, soapui, couchbase, sql++

I am trying create document in an existing bucket in CouchBase using N1QL query. I am using soapUI to send request to localhost CouchBase server.
I used this link to gain knowledge
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html

```
N1QL:
GET http://localhost:8093/query/service?statement = ?select * from beer use keys ["beername::abcc"]
```

this works well to fetch doc

How can I do the same to post json data, creating new document.

I tried:

```
POST http://localhost:8093/query/service.
```

In request body

```
INSERT INTO `beer` ( KEY, VALUE ) 
VALUES 
 ( 
"k001", 
{ "id": "01", "type": "airline"} 
 ) 
RETURNING META().id as docid, *;
```

I am getting

> "Error processing json request"

Answer (score 1):

From the `N1QL` documentation:

> For POST requests, you can specify the parameters in the request body
>   in URL-encoded format or JSON format.

So seems that you can't directly specify the statement in the request body, you've to put in URL-encoded format or as *JSON* like `{ "statement" : "select ..." }`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the INSERT statment directly in the body of the request:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8093/query/service -d 'statement=INSERT INTO `beer` ( KEY, VALUE ) VALUES ( "k002", { "id": "01", "type": "airline"} ) RETURNING META().id as docid, *;'
```

Or in postman http client:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Also, see the latest docs as well. http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html